# module 'pandas_datareader' has no attribute 'get_data_yahoo'

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

I'm trying to get stock market history using pandas-datareader as specified in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433076/download-history-stock-prices-automatically-from-yahoo-finance-in-python).

I've installed pandas-datareader with:
`conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda pandas-datareader`
I'm running on windows 10, with pycharm, and anaconda3 interpreter

I'm trying to run the very basic:

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
pdr.get_data_yahoo('AAPL')
```

But I get an error:

  `File "D:/Dropbox/Duo/documents docs/Projects/F500AquisitionQuality/m_and_a_quality/stock_utils.py", line 2, in <module>
    pdr.get_data_yahoo('AAPL')
AttributeError: module 'pandas_datareader' has no attribute 'get_data_yahoo'`

Please note that the filename has nothing to do with pandas as in [this reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/51h2q9/attributeerror_module_pandas_datareader_has_no/) (the only related thing i could find online)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with get_data_yahoo in version 0.4.0 (because Yahoo changed API).

To fix it you can install version 0.4.1
(it's not merged yet https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/pull/331 as for May 20 2017)

Following code helped me. I cloned pandas-datareader source code, changed branch, installed package from source code using pip3

`git clone https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader
cd pandas-datareader/
git remote add rgkimball http://github.com/rgkimball/pandas-datareader
git fetch rgkimball fix-yahoo
git checkout fix-yahoo
pip3 uninstall pandas_datareader
python3 setup.py install`

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't figure out the problem, but I did solve it by running

`pip uninstall pandas-datareader`

and then 
`pip install pandas-datareader`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you just need 2 things
First uninstall the lib -

```
pip uninstall pandas-datareader
```

And then need to install it using **pip3** (Please notice it is pip3)

```
pip3 install pandas-datareader
```